# Android Studio UI use design or text?

Tags: android, android-studio

Kind of new to programming, especially with apps
In Android Studio, which is the 'proper' way of designing the UI? The drag-and-drop or manually through code? (Design or Text)

Also, is AndroidStudio the best way to code for apps?

Sorry if its a silly question, new to this stufff

Comment: It depends on people to people. I better write myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drag and drop may make a lot of sense when combined with appropriate coding in xml. As @Rai said, it is important to learn how things work via code in xml - but I would like to add that learning things in xml will make the transition to editing views programmatically (dynamically in your java classes), much easier.

Sometimes, however, such as when you are using a constraint layout (a more advanced but very useful layout to use that improves performance in many cases), it is a lot more efficient to get the look you want in the design tab. Check out this tutorial: https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html

In general you should make sure you UNDERSTAND what you are doing when you are making android apps (and coding in general), because if you are just messing around in a design editor you may end up doing things that slow down your user experience and can be done more efficiently. As long as you understand what you are doing (and it is legal) doing whatever is efficient for you as a developer and for your user experience is what is 'proper' - it is an engineering disciple after all.

You should use android studio 2.3x when you are starting out. It used to be true that eclipse was used, but now Google wants you to transition to android studio.

Comment: Thank you very much! What resources do you think would be best to tackle XML and android in general?

Comment: The google documentation is good for learning android - if that is your focus, you should learn android and pick up xml along the way. The best way to learn android is by building projects - reading documentation is less interesting if it is not relevant, and does not stick.

Comment: If courseware is your way of learning Udacity has a course on android development (totally free) that you should check out. I am working on their nanodegree program and I can attest it is good stuff ! Remember that if you think an answer is helpful to click the checkmark as accepting it.

Answer (score 1):

> You should not rely on drag-and-drop. Its better you know manually
>   what a code does before you use drag-and-drop functionality. For
>   me in android drag-and-drop is not that usable. You should learn all
>   the attribute, properties and know the relationship between views by writing it manually rather than
>   using 'drag-and-drop' and ask yourself at the end how UI works and
>   rendered.

Comment: That was my original thought. The android developer website tutorial uses drag-and-drop which is why I had my concern. Thank you for clearing it up!